# Unauthorized error for ISAPI service of SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, isapi

I have create `ISAPI` service in "ISAPI" folder of hive.

Now I want to access this service using REST API. but I'm getting unauthorized error when try to call it.

**IDemoService.cs** code (Interface file):

```
namespace ISAPIDemo.ISAPI
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDemoService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "DemoServiceCall({SampleValue})")]
        string DemoServiceCall(string SampleValue);
    }
}
```

**DemoService.svc** code:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="ISAPIDemo.DemoService"
    CodeBehind="DemoService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

**DemoService.svc.cs** code:

```
namespace ISAPIDemo.ISAPI
{
    [BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public sealed class SampleService : IDemoService
    {            
        public string DemoServiceCall(string SampleValue)
        {
            // Write the string to a file.
            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.txt");
            file.WriteLine("In Demo Service");

            file.Close();
            return "test";
        }

    }
}
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getISAPIData();
});

function getISAPIData() {   
    var serviceUri = "http://xxxxxxxxx/_vti_bin/DemoService.svc/DemoServiceCall(test)";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: serviceUri,
        dataType: "json",
        success:
            function (response) {
                alert('Success' + response);                
            },
        error:
            function (err) {
                alert('Error ' + err);
            }
    });
}
```

these much code I have written for service and call it into js. Is it any thing that I had missed?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in writing to a file on the server? Seems like an odd operation

Comment: yes, problem is not in file write code because if i will remove file write code then also it will give same error.

Answer (score 1):

Getting WCF Rest to work from SharePoint Hive context is tricky.

Even in **DemoService.svc**  also you need to include assembly token and all the data so that the service request is filled by dll in assembly.

For Ex:
`Service="rest.Impl,yourdllName,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=2c644798ac000000"`

*All together i suggest you to host the WCF Rest as seperate site rather in SharePoint Hive.*

Comment: is this code right? <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
    Service="ISAPIDemo.DemoService"
    CodeBehind="DemoService.svc.cs"
    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

Comment: I have create one more service and hosted it in layout folder instead of ISAPI folder. It is allowing to make call using ajax. but ISAPI service will not

Comment: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ISAPIDemo.DemoService,YourDLLName,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=2c644798ac00000" CodeBehind="ISAPIDemo.svc.cs"%>

try like above